# Duda con timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, entrada, timestamp

tengo una duda, no se como se utiliza el tipo de dato timestamp y no encuentro la manera de que con un input seleccionar la fecha y convertirlo en un timestamp para ingresarlo a la base de datos.

cualquier información me sirviria, muchas gracias

Comment: Recuerda que debes poner lo que has intentado. Ahora, ya intentaste pasar el date de un input por Javascript y hacer un parsing a `new Date()`? Te recomiendo el framework moment.js.

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). lee [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pregunto:¿hay algo mas que puedas compartir en tu pregunta? *(código, enlaces de investigación, descripción de lo que hayas intentado, etc)*. [edit] la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Si lo que deseas es capturar una fecha de un input puedes hacer lo siguiente*:
Ejemplo

-En el archivo HTML: "Recuerda cambiar el input a un tipo de dato **date** y recuerda el name asignado al input "

```html
<input id="f_inicio" type="date"  name="f_ini" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuando inicia...??" >
```

-En el archivo PHP: Por el metodo POST traemos el valor del input antes mencionado utilizando el name y lo asignamos a una variable.

```js
$f_ini = $_POST["f_ini"];
```

-En el mismo codigo PHP reescribimos el valor con el tipo de dato date que se desee:

```js
$f_inibd = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($f_ini));
```

Y esa ultima variable ("$f_inibd") es la que guardamos en la base de datos.

Comentarios: Luego de traer el valor de tipo date del input a php lo asignamos a una varible, y luego transformamos esa varible nuevamente para poder ordenar el formato en que queremos que ese tipo de dato se guarde en la base de datos, es por esa razon que reasignamos la varible.

Si desee saber los tipos de formato date que puede guardar verifique este [link](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me funciono muy bien, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo desde la base de datos con un `default`, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
create table if not exists readings(
    id int primary key auto_increment not null,
    timestamp datetime not null default now()
)engine = InnoDB character set utf8 collate utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Tu `insert` se vería de la siguiente manera:

```
insert into  (id, timestamp) values (null, default);
```

De esta manera estamos obteniendo el `datetime` exacto en la que se realizo el `insert` dentro del `servidor` de `base datos`.